# Mysql query broswer not showing schemata (databases)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

[image: Mysql Query Browser it doesnot show schemata]

Hello, people, I'd appreciate it if you could assist me with this problem. I'm using workbench and mysql, and I have a few schemata (databases) in my sql. However, when I log in using Mysql Query Browser, it doesn't show my schemata (databases), but it does when I use workbench.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Query Browser was the first visual DB query tool from MySQL. Since a decade or so it has been replaced by MySQL Workbench and does not support servers beyond 4.x (IIRC).